# WYGWAM - text align center?

Tags: wygwam, html, text-formatting

I just updated to Wygwams latest version and I don't see the "text align" option anymore. How do I restore it?

Answer (score 4):

We just released [Wygwam 3.1.2](http://docs.pixelandtonic.com/wygwam/changelog.html#wygwam-3-1-2) which brought back the text alignment buttons.

Answer (score 3):

Had this problem too. Looks like they removed it from the default set-up. First thing to check is under 'themes/third_party/wygwam/lib/ckeditor/plugins' you have the 'justify' plugin installed.
If not just download it here (http://ckeditor.com/addon/justify?page=1) and place the whole folder in the plugins folder.

Next you need to be in 'system/expressionengine/third_party/wygwam/helper.php'

Around line 67 you'll see them setting up a multi-dimensional array in the 'tb_groups' function (this is where the CP Editor Configuration is pulling it's list of toolbar options from).
Add a new array like so

```
array('JustifyLeft', 'JustifyCenter', 'JustifyRight', 'JustifyBlock')
```

Around line 577 you'll see them loading in some extra Plugins (there was 'wygwam' and 'readmore' in my file. You need to load the 'justify' extra in the same way.

```
$extraPlugins[] = 'justify';
```

You should now have the 4 alignment options in the EE Wygwam editor configuration pages to drag and drop into your toolbar and those options should also display in both the EE new/edit entry pages and also in Safecracker forms.